# rails find all comments where the post's user_id = user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

A little bit complicated of a query here. Three relevant tables: users, posts, and comments. The user has_many posts and comments, the posts belong_to the user and has_many comments, and the comments belong_to a user and a post. That said, I'm trying in Rails to, in my controller, find all the comments that a user has received on all his posts. I tried this:

```
@comments = Comment.where(:post_id.user => @user.id)
```

But that didn't really work out. This is probably a simple solution, help?

Comment: This might help you to know you can and can't do :) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to [join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) the posts table for that:

```
@comments = Comment.joins(:post).where(:posts => { :user_id => @user.id })
```

Comment: what if i need User's all the posts and its comment on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like:

```
@user = User.find(@user.id, :include => :comments)

<% @user.comments.each do |comment| %>
   <%= comment.id %> <br/>
   <%= comment.text %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This seems much easier.

Comment: @scottastic, it doesn't do what is asked for in the question though.

Comment: This gets the comments a user made, not all the comments on user received on his posts.